# Remove bullet points from chart.js legend

Tags: css, chart.js

I'm using chart.js as per [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vrwjfg9z/) example.

My legend is showing bullet points alongside each legend item and I don't know why.  Occurs in multiple browers.  Here is an image of what I am getting:

[image]

I have tried to add "list-style-type: none;" into the css but this did not make a difference for me.

Any ideas please?
JSFiddle code below:

```
**html**
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<canvas id="myChart" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>

**js**
var data = [
{
value: 61,
color: "#09355C",
label: "Label 1"
}, {
value: 11,
color: "#CBCBCB",
label: "Label 2"
}, {
value: 28,
color: "#B61B12",
label: "Label 3"
}];

var options = {
segmentShowStroke: false,
animateRotate: true,
animateScale: false,
percentageInnerCutout: 50,
tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>%"
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);
document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();

**css**
.chart-legend li span{
display: inline-block;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any bullets in your jsfiddle demo. Can you please give me a screenshot of what is a problem?

Comment: Thanks, http://imgur.com/9HnPOsW

Comment: Which browser are you using ? it seems that it has a different behaviour than ours (works fine with last version of Chrome). Have you tried the hack ul { list-style-type:none !important; }   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `list-style-type: none;` to the `li` elements i.e. something like

```
.chart-legend li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Your current CSS ruleset targets `.chart-legend li span` - adding `list-style-type: none;` there will not help.

Comment: Legend, thanks very much, that's exactly what I needed :D